# Drive resistor value for crystal in USB hub

Tags: usb, oscillator, crystal, usb-hub

I am designing a one-up two-down USB hub based on a TUSB2036 USB FS hub. I am going to use a 6MHz crystal as recommended in their datasheet: [image: Reccomended configuration for crystal]
The usage of the resistor doesn't really make sense to me with the explanation that they give. There is also a FAQ app note on this chip from TI. They say:

[image: FAQ of crystal and Rd selection]

This explanation makes much more sense to me; the resistor is used to make sure that the crystal isn't driven with too much current. They have an example schematic that uses a 2k2 resistor value, but they also recommend a 1k5...

They explain how to use the potentiometer to "tune" the value of the resistor using a potentiometer, but they don't say how you are able to see if it is "overdriven".
So, am I safe to use a resistor of around 1k5 - 2k2? How am I to know if the crystal is being overdriven?

I assume I check the "XTAL2" node with a scope and confirm that it is oscillating at 6MHz, but I'm not positive.

Comment: The do say *"Note that overdriving of the crystal **can be observed on the oscillator output signal**"* But I don't know (yet) how you can determine it from that output signal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/00849a.pdf

> RS is a series resistor that is selected to prevent overdriving the crystal. It is not often needed if gain (Clock mode), C1 and C2 are selected properly. If the circuit is being overdriven and a lower gain Clock mode cannot be selected, then adding impedance with RS can decrease gain.
>   **This overdrive can be visually demonstrated** by looking at the Osc-Out pin, which is the driven pin, with an oscilloscope. Connecting the probe to the Osc-In pin will load the pin too much and negatively affect performance.
>   **The output signal should not be clipped or squashed. Overdriving the crystal can also lead to the circuit jumping to a higher harmonic.**

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Looks like it would have been easy to tell from testing if it was overdriven, but not if it wasn't! Thanks :)

Comment: @KyleHunter, you never know for sure without knowing your crystal's ESR and "negative resistance" of your internal circuit. Too much of series resistor might kill the circuit ability to oscillate and start reliably. This is a "gray engineering" area. Also, normal OSC circuit use a fairy weak drivers (and often configurable via internal registers), so there is no worry about overdriving.

Comment: @Ale..chenski Hmm OK. So you're suggesting to start on the low side of the resistor values? Since having it be overdriven is less likely than underdriven?